# How to pop up the default message window on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, popup, message

I want to implement a function which can pop up the default message window on ubuntu(gnome is used). It is just like the Rhythmbox dose when a new song is played and pop this window. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.04 and later use a new notification server NotifyOSD. Checkout the NotifyOSD [Development Guidelines.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines) Here's also a simple [example in python](http://www.dscripts.net/2010/09/07/create-custom-notification-on-your-ubuntu-desktop-using-python/).